# How to Naturally Sort Pathlib objects in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I am trying to create a sorted list of files in the `./pages` directory.  This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import glob
from pathlib import Path


# sorted( l, key=lambda a: int(a.split("-")[1]) )
image_list = []

for filename in Path('./pages').glob('*.jpg'):
#     sorted( i, key=lambda a: int(a.split("_")[1]) )
#     im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(filename)

print(*image_list, sep = "\n")
```

current output:

```
pages/page_1.jpg  
pages/page_10.jpg  
pages/page_11.jpg  
pages/page_12.jpg  
pages/page_2.jpg  
pages/page_3.jpg  
pages/page_4.jpg  
pages/page_5.jpg  
pages/page_6.jpg  
pages/page_7.jpg  
pages/page_8.jpg  
pages/page_9.jpg
```

Expected Output:

```
pages/page_1.jpg   
pages/page_2.jpg  
pages/page_3.jpg  
pages/page_4.jpg  
pages/page_5.jpg  
pages/page_6.jpg  
pages/page_7.jpg  
pages/page_8.jpg  
pages/page_9.jpg  
pages/page_10.jpg  
pages/page_11.jpg  
pages/page_12.jpg
```

I've tried the solutions found in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort), but they don't work because the pathlib files are class objects, and not strings.  They only appear as filenames when I print them.

For example:

```
print(filename) # pages/page_1.jpg  
print(type(filename)) # <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>
```

Finally, this is working code. Thanks to all.

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import natsort

def merge_to_single_image():
    image_list1 = []
    image_list2 = []
    image_list3 = []
    image_list4 = []

    for filename in Path('./pages').glob('*.jpg'):
        image_list1.append(filename)

    for i in image_list1:
        image_list2.append(i.stem)
    #     print(type(i.stem))

    image_list3 = natsort.natsorted(image_list2, reverse=False)

    for i in image_list3:
        i = str(i)+ ".jpg"
        image_list4.append(Path('./pages', i))

    images = [Image.open(i) for i in image_list4]
    # for a vertical stacking it is simple: use vstack
    images_combined = np.vstack(images)
    images_combined = Image.fromarray(images_combined)
    images_combined.save('Single_image.jpg')
```

Comment: Does all files have the same ```page_``` prefix?

Comment: Filename is generated by me, so it is not compulsory to have `page_`. It may be also as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, ... , 10.jpg, 11.jpg

Comment: You just need to turn the path object into a string first.  Try this: `for filename in sorted(Path('./pages').glob('*.jpg'), 
                       key=lambda a: int(str(a).split("_")[1])):`

Comment: **Solution:** since filenames are created by you: Write file names adding padded zeros, like [bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73533144/1207193). Sort will be easy.

Answer (score 6):

Just for posterity, maybe this is more succinct?

```
natsorted(list_of_pathlib_objects, key=str)
```

Comment: Note that this uses the `natsort` module which has to be installed, as it is not part of the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

One can use [natsort lib](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/howitworks.html?highlight=pathlib#sorting-filesystem-paths) ([pip install natsort](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/). It should look simple too.

[! This works, at least tested for versions 5.5 and 7.1 (current)]

```
from natsort import natsorted

image_list = Path('./pages').glob('*.jpg')
image_list = natsorted(image_list, key=str)

# Or convert list of paths to list of string and (naturally)sort it, then convert back to list of paths
image_list = [Path(p) for p in natsorted([str(p) for p in image_list ])]
```

Comment: If paths have different parents, look in [docs](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/howitworks.html?highlight=pathlib#sorting-filesystem-paths)

Answer (score 4):

Note that `sorted`  doesn't sort your data in place, but returns a new list, so you have to iterate on its output.

In order to get your sorting key, which is the integer value at the end of your filename:

- You can first take the [stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) of your path, which is its final component without extension (so, for example, `'page_13'`).
- Then, it is better to split it once from the right, in order to be safe in case your filename contains other underscores in the first part, like `'some_page_33.jpg'`.
- Once converted to `int`, you have the key you want for sorting.

So, your code could look like:

```
for filename in sorted(Path('./pages').glob('*.jpg'), 
                       key=lambda path: int(path.stem.rsplit("_", 1)[1])):

    print(filename)
```

Sample output:

```
pages/ma_page_2.jpg
pages/ma_page_11.jpg
pages/ma_page_13.jpg
pages/ma_page_20.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use like this...

```
from pathlib import Path
```

#### - sorted by name:

```
sorted(Path('anywhere/you/want').glob('*.jpg'))
```

#### - sorted by modification time:

```
import os
sorted(Path('anywhere/you/want').glob('*.jpg'), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

#### - sorted by size:

```
import os
sorted(Path('anywhere/you/want').glob('*.jpg'), key=os.path.getsize)
```

etc.

**Hint**: since filenames are also created by you. Write file names adding padded zeros, like:

```
for i in range(100):        
    with open('filename'+f'_{i:03d}','wb'):  # py3.6+ fstring        
       # write your file stuff...
    # py3.3+ 'filename'+'_{:03d}'.format(i) for str.format()
 ...
 'filename_007',
 'filename_008',
 'filename_009',
 'filename_010',
 'filename_011',
 'filename_012',
 'filename_013',
 'filename_014',
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not as easy as it sounds, "natural" sorting can be quite challenging, especially with potential arbitrary input strings, e.g what if you have "69_helloKitty.jpg" in your data?
I used https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort a while ago for a similar problem, maybe it helps you.